# Tips for Using 3D Space to Create a 2D 3D Character

Tags: animation, 3d-view, grease-pencil, 2d

I was wondering if any tips existed for creating with the new 2D feature in Blender a character that is 3Dionally drawn. I managed to achieve it a little but when I rotated the camera the obvious reality is that it a 3D space. So some strokes at one angle work and others don't.

So I was wondering if any tips exist for using Grease to draw a 2D character that is 3D so when I rotate the camera at a different angle it won't need redo drawing every time.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question is too broad and vague, try rephrasing it to focus on specific problems that you have encountered. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48499/can-blender-make-2d-flash-animations-like-adobe-animate/

Comment: My apologies. What I merely was asking -- was any tips for in the 3D workspace drawing with the grease pencil a 3d character that I can rotate the camera around without having to redraw each angle. So essentially drawing a character that has 3 dimensions/ way to draw in 3D a 2D character with the grease pencil.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask